# Castle Windsor - Registering and Resolving Cached and Uncached Implementation of same Interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a service interface, ICustomerService, and have it implemented by two types:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    // stuff
}

public class CachedCustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    public CachedCustomerService(CustomerService service) { }
}
```

The cached service then just caches and delegates to the normal service.

For registration I have ICustomerService resolve to CachedCustomerService and then CustomerService is just registered for its own type.

This works fine.

What I'm wondering is if I can make CachedCustomerService require an interface instead of the concrete CustomerService.  The reason is that we might end up with two types of CustomerService and I want to avoid (if possible) a cached version specific to each one.

So the constructor of CachedCustomerService would change to:

```
public class CachedCustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    // notice the ICustomerService
    public CachedCustomerService(ICustomerService service) { }
}
```

I have total control over the registration but the resolution is done by the bowls of asp.net mvc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do with Castle Windsor is like [this article](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-4-how-to.html) suggests.
So in your case you simply need to register your customer service in order with your cached service first:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer()
.Register(
Component.For(typeof(ICustomerService)).ImplementedBy(typeof(CachedCustomerService)),
Component.For(typeof(ICustomerService)).ImplementedBy(typeof(CustomerService))
);
```

Then Cached Customer service can use `ICustomerService` as inner/wrapped object as follows:

```
public class CachedCustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private ICustomerService _customerService;
    public CachedCustomerService(ICustomerService service)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cached Customer service created");
        this._customerService = service;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cached Customer service running");
        this._customerService.Run();
    }
}
```

And then the resolution is as normal:

```
ICustomerService service = container.Resolve<ICustomerService>();
service.Run();
```